# How do I fix this layout?

Tags: android, layout

[image]Why is my layout for my book items appearing so close together, the book images should be closer to each other, as shown in the attached image. I already tried changing the gravity and orientation but that did not solve my problem.  Some help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance[image]

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bookImage"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bookTitleTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/bookImage"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:text="A boy with tigers heart"
            android:textColor="#424242"
            android:textSize="@dimen/album_title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bookAuthorTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/bookTitleTv"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/songs_count_padding_bottom"
            android:text="by Georeg Lopeaa"
            android:textSize="@dimen/songs_count"
            android:textStyle="italic" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/deleteTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/ic_album_overflow_height"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bookAuthorTv"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/bookAuthorTv"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/album_title_padding"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/songs_count_padding_bottom"
            android:text="@string/vertical_ellipsis"
            android:textSize="@dimen/songs_count" />


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout
```

Comment: Looks like `wrap_content` width on everything is the problem. The textviews stretch to fit the long text, and then everything else gets pushed around by that.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by removing one of your Linear layouts, it is redundant to have linear Layout be the child view of a linear layout.

Now in your TextViews try setting the layout_width to match_parent instead of wrap_content.